# Timthumb Rewrite Rule for NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm new to Nginx and have a problem with the rewriting of timthumb urls.
My old Apache Code looks like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)  img.php?src=http://helmok.gnitter.de/crawler/raw_images/$1&h=136w=150&zc=1 [L]
```

So as you can see the requestet file should be attached to $1.
I tried to make my own but this seems to be totally wrong

```
location /cache/thumb/ {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /img.php?src=https://helmok.gnitter.de/crawler/raw_images/$1&h=350&w=350&zc=1 

    }
```

I hope that someone could have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The `$1` will be our `$uri` in this condition

```
location /cache/thumb/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /img.php?src=https://helmok.gnitter.de/crawler/raw_images/$uri&h=350&w=350&zc=1 
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad and thank you. Sadly this is not working. In that case he should grab the requestet filename so as example www.test.de/myimage.jpg = myimage.jpg . If i understand this right uri = url?

Comment: for `example.com/cache/thumb/image.jpg` URI will be `/cache/thumb/image.jpg` if you want just the image name them you could try using `$request_filename` instead

Comment: I tried now as example `location /cache/thumb/ {
    try_files $uri $request_filename/ /img.php?src=https://helmok.gnitter.de/crawler/raw_images/$request_filename&h=350&w=350&zc=1;
}`  The result is sadly again the same. File not found

Comment: add `rewrite_log on;` and rewrite information will be logged in `error_log` if you defined one, will help you debug

Comment: maybe `img.php` it self is not in the right place, is it inside `/cache/thumb` or the root in `media`

Comment: Hi Mohammad, i added this line in my serverblock http://pastebin.com/t21exB88 . There is sadly nothing in the error log, yust a 404 error but no rewrite message.